# Example to write a rest API in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest

What is best way to write a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API using Node.js?

Comment: What kind of API do you want to write? Write down some of your ideas, starting points etc. Otherwise no one will help you Im afraid

Comment: just a sample service with returning something

Comment: You might have [better luck at Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-approach-to-build-a-REST-API-with-Node-js?share=1).

Comment: thank you for your kind information

Answer (score -1):

Conceptually I don't think that you have to do anything extra for a RESTful API. The same mechanism that you develop to render web pages can be used for a RESTful API. You just have make sure that at the end of task you send [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data.

```
res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));  //Or
res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
```

However to be **more organised and standardised**, there is a general practise to add an extra router for the RESTful API along with some generic activities. I suggest you [follow this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4).

Additionally you might have to consider no-authentication or separate authentication for various access rights. and may be  API key for security.

Comment: some monkey is trying to down vote your question and my answer. but  I still think there is value in your question from the perspective of new comers. So I will let this answer be here even if there are 1000 down vote